# How do I get tikzpictures to overlap on the same page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, boxes

I have two complex TikZ drawings that need to overlap (appear on the same page). I can't put them into one `tikzpicture`, because different `scale` parameters need to be applied to them. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=2]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [white]
    (0,1) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, scale=1]
  \fill [red]
    (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

**This is what I actually need:**

[image]

The `overlay` option doesn't seem to work as expected. Using `(current page.center)` in the second `tikzpicture` doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really need to use a second `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Yes. :( As I explained, I need to use a different `scale` for each figure.

Comment: You can use a single one and use `\begin{scope}[scale=2]   \end{scope}` instead of duplicate the scale in the whole figure.

Comment: Sounds good! Care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can superpose two different tikzpicures if you have some reference from the first one. In this case, as you already have a `image` node in your first picture, just adding `remember picture` option to it, this `image` node will be available outside of it. Therefore, you can use it as reference inside the second `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=2, remember picture]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [white]
    (0,1) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, scale=1]
  \fill [red]
    (image) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answers the exact question in the title, although @Sigur has the better approach to my specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a single `tikzpicture` and put everything you want to scale inside a `scope` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
 \begin{scope}[scale=2]
  \node (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \fill [white] (0,1) circle [radius=1];
 \end{scope}
\fill [red] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. 1 hour reading docs > 1 hour fruitless trial and error > 5 minutes on SE > "OMG there are _"scopes"_?!

Comment: This is the smarter way to do this, but @Ignasi has the answer to the actual question in the title. Wish I could accept both answers. :(

Comment: @kontextify, don't worry. Feel free to choose one.